# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, video orientation stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, avcapture

I have an iPhone camera app in which I use the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. When someone takes a picture/stillImage this is shown in a new ViewController. The magic happens once this view controller is dismissed.

The whole app rotates properly, both viewcontroller; but for one exception. If I take a picture in one orientation, rotate the device in the new ViewController and then go back to the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer the whole layer rotates along just fine, except for the image, so suddenly the input is presented sideways through the previewLayer.

I have checked, and tried setting the frame for the PreviewLayer, but this all seems fine, the values I see when debugging are all correct. It is just the image that is displayed that is skewed. Rotating the device back and forth fixes this issue during use.

Has anyone seen this before, and does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: is this for iphone or ipad? For iphone stick with portrait mode. I have seen some goofy things happen with AVCapture if iphone viewcontroller is allowed to rotate.

Comment: @SamBudda It is for iPhone, and as I said. It works perfect except for that one situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the previewLayer's connection's videoOrientation when the interface  rotates

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because the viewController is not the active one at that moment, therefore this function is not called. However this did point me in the right direction. The solution is to write your own function, pass it the orientation from the active view and call it with a notification when the active ViewController on top of it changes orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Since `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated in iOS 8, I change the video orientation of the connection in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past.
Once dismissed camera controller you could refresh view rotation with this:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *topView = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[topView removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:topView];
```

So, removing top most view on shown window and resetting it on window, it should refresh view rotation properly.

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to fix my problem at all. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, instead of changing `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` frame, you could try to put it in a  container `UIView`, and set this container's frame. (I fixed a 'sizing' bug on ÀVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`this way : sizing directly PreviewLayer had no effect, but sizing its containing`UIView` worked).

Or,
maybe you can force orientation in your viewController `viewWillAppear` (or `viewDidAppear` ?)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // try and force current orientation
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = application.statusBarOrientation;
    [application setStatusBarOrientation:currentOrientation animated:animated];
}
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Since the interfaceOrientation is deprecated, the up to date swift 2.0 solution shall be:

```
let previewLayerConnection = self.previewLayer.connection
let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.rawValue)
previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = orientation!
```